# Excel Drag/Drop to Get Filename and Path

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form "UserForm1" and am using the following code to obtain the filename and path of a file that the user has dragged and dropped into the TreeView located on the userform.

```
 Public Sub TreeView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    StrPath = Data.Files(1)
    Debug.Print StrPath
    Call PrintPath
End Sub
```

Then in the UserForm_Initialize I have

```
TreeView1.OLEDropMode = ccOLEDropManual
```

I know this code is getting the path and name because I'm able to debug.print it. However, my issue is I can't get this filename and path to be utilized in a module. For instance I have tried to do the following for the simplest of uses (to print the filename and path to cell A1):

```
    Public Sub PrintPath()
UserForm1.TreeView1.StrPath = Range("A1").Value

'StrPath.Value = Range("A1").Value

'UserForm1.StrPath.Value = Range("A1").Value

'Range("A1").Value = UserForm1.Data.Files(1)

End Sub
```

All of the commented lines are other versions I have attempted with no avail.
I typically get Object does not exist. Sometimes 424 errors.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Please and thank you!

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do this woould be to pass the path as an argument to `PrintPath`

```vb
Public Sub TreeView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, _
                     Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    Dim strPath
    strPath = Data.Files(1)
    Debug.Print strPath
    PrintPath strPath '<< pass in the path
End Sub

Public Sub PrintPath(sPath)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = sPath
End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice. I am fairly new to VBA so I am trying to understand this code. What does the (sPath) do? I'm not used to seeing things in the parenthesis of Subs.

Comment: It's quite normal for methods to have *parameters* - eg see https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/arguments.htm

Comment: So I think what I'm still not getting is why the argument in the sub becomes sPath rather than strPath?

Comment: When you pass an argument into a method, the variable *name* in the calling method is irrelevant - the only relevant thing is the variable *content*.  Otherwise, it would be very awkward trying to write code which made extensive use of parameters/arguments, because you'd need to synchronize variable names between calling/called methods...

Answer (score 0):

I have just now figured out the answer. In the UserForm1 Code I did

```
Option Explicit
Public StrPath As Variant
```

Then in the module I was able to use it with

```
UserForm1.StrPath
```

i.e.

```
Range("A1").Value = UserForm1.StrPath
```